# Persistently looping CAAnimations

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation

A `CAAnimation` may be looped by setting its `repeatCount` to `CGFLOAT_MAX`. Following some events, however, the animation will be removed and won't be restored automatically. For example:

- When application enters background: The animation must be re-added
  manually when returning from background.
- When navigating away from the controller: In some cases the animation
  won't be restored after popping from the stack.

My general question is: What events cause animations to be removed; how do I ensure that they are re-added?